# PHP Slow to process soap request via browser but fine on the command line

Tags: soap, php-5.3, php

I am trying to connect to an external SOAP service using PHP and have written a small php test script that just connects to the service and performs a simple request to check everything is working.

This all works correctly but when I run via a browser request, it is very slow taking somewhere in the region of 40s to establish the initial connection.  When I do the same request using the exact same script on the command line, it goes through straight away.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?

Cheers

Comment: For what its worth, I've just tried re-writing the test script as a php shell script and then used another script to execute that using passthru().  To my mind, this should have meant that, even when run from a browser, the test script should still have behaved as if it were being executed on the command line however I am still seeing the same problematic behaviour.

Comment: I think it's the compression but can you give us more details or the url?

Comment: I can't usefully give out any urls i'm afraid as its a paid for service and everything is quite locked down so I don't think the urls will work without ip's being registered with the provider and without authentication details.  I'd be happy to provide anything else that may be useful tho - What else would help?

Comment: Just try to do a google speed test yourself to the url and see what it says. It's a very good tool.

Comment: I have tracked down the problem to a users/permissions issue - if I switch to the apache user, and run the script on the command line, I get the same slow behaviour.  So my guess now is that the library is trying to write somewhere apache doesn't have permission to write to and I guess its just a case of hunting around to find what it is that needs to be made writable by apache.  Thanks all for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 3):

PHP caches the wsdl in /tmp.  If you run from the command line first, the cache file will be owned by whatever user you're running the script as, and apache won't be able to read the cache.  The wsdl will have to be downloaded and parsed every time which will be slow.

Check the permissions of /tmp/wsdl*.

Comment: sudo chmod 777 /tmp/wsdl-* did the trick for me. (not for production servers)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `external SOAP service` trying to check your IP, and your server has ICMP allowed, when your local network - not.
Anyway, this question might be answered more clearly by administrator of `external SOAP service` :)

Comment: Yeah they were the first people I tried but unfortunately they are not very helpful.  when i run the script on the command line, I am ssh'ed into the web server so any checks back like that should work the same right?  Ie if there were some DNS nastiness going on, wouldn't it would affect both contexts the same?

Comment: well, ssh works usually at 21 port, not at 80. Maybe it's a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a difference between the `php.ini`s that are being used?

On a standard ubuntu server installation:

`diff /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

//edit:

Another difference might be in the include paths. Had this trouble myself on a local test server, it didn't actually use the soap class that was included (it didn't include anything, because the search paths weren't valid), but it included the built-in `soap_client` class.

Comment: This sounds promising but unfortunately this is a Centos server and I could only find the one php.ini.  In the process of looking though, I noticed that the user server variable was different in the 2 contexts. So clearly there is a difference between the 2 configurations that are being loaded but I can't seem to find where this might be.  Will keep hunting.  Thanks for the suggestion